# Only print a certain number of cells in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I am pulling some data from a database in PHP, however I only want to print it, if that record number is a certain value. For example, if it's less than result number 11. I want to do pagination you see.
My database has around 30 records for a specific area, but i only want it to print 10 on one page. Here is my code

```
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $descriptiontype = $row["description"];
        $minorscript = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $descriptiontype), 0, 7))."<a href = 'ticket.php?id=GS" . $row["id"]. "'>...(See More)</a>";

        $currentstatus = $row["status"];

        $filevar = $row["screenshot_url"];
        if ($filevar === "") {
            $filelink = "</td><td>None</td><td>";
        }
        else {
            $filelink = "</td><td><a href='upload/" . $row["screenshot_url"] . "'>View</a></td><td>";
        }


        echo "<tr><td><a href = 'ticket.php?id=GS" . $row["id"]. "'>Edit</a></td><td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>". $row["raised_by"]. "</td><td>" . $row["date_time"] . "</td><td><a href='" . $row["webaddress"] . "'>" . $row["webaddress"] . "</a></td><td>" . $minorscript . $filelink . "<div class = '$currentstatus'>" . $row["status"] . "</div></td></tr>"  ;
    }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Comment: Give us the content of $sql.

Comment: SELECT id, raised_by, date_time, webaddress, description, screenshot_url, owner, status FROM gensupport order by id desc

Comment: "do pagination" is pretty broad.  Are you asking specifically what keywords to use in SQL to paginate results?  Are you having trouble maintaining the state of what page the user is on?  Something else?  You might also benefit from any of a large variety of tools which handle much of the client-side heavy lifting for you.  For example: https://www.datatables.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you $sql query, you can do `OFFSET X FETCH NEXT Y ROWS ONLY` with X and Y values from your PHP.

For exemple :

```
SELECT id, raised_by, date_time, webaddress, description, screenshot_url, owner, status 
FROM gensupport 
ORDER BY id DESC
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

This is perfect for pagination, because the X will skip the X first values, the Y is the number of rows.

Comment: Here is my sql SELECT id, raised_by, date_time, webaddress, description, screenshot_url, owner, status FROM gensupport order by id desc

Comment: Edited, is this what are you looking for ?